# How can I extract Data displayed after clicking a button?

Tags: python, web, product, screen-scraping, clicking

I am Trying to Web Scrape this site https://www.platformone-eg.com/en/products, how can I **scrape** data displayed after clicking Product Details Button like this

```
<a wire:click.prevent="product_details(15662)" class="btn btn-outline-info rounded btn-block mt-2">Product Details</a>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: button like this   <a wire:click.prevent="product_details(15662)" class="btn btn-outline-info rounded btn-block mt-2">Product Details</a>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of web scraping, use the Selenium library to automate the browser and then you'll have a full web session you can control.

Comment: how i do that please ?